# Has many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this relationship in a Rails app

```
class Folder
  has_many :elements
end

class Element
  belongs_to :folder
end
```

My problem is this code doesn't work

```
element = Element.first
a_folder.elements << element
element.save!
a_folder.save!
```

, but this one works:

```
element.folder = a_folder
element.save!
```

Anyone can tell me why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Rails [documentation](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

> Adding an object to a collection
>   (has_many  or has_and_belongs_to_many)
>   automatically saves that object,
>   except if the parent object (the owner
>   of the collection) is not yet stored
>   in the database.

So if `@folder` is already saved then `@folder.elements << @element` should work.

You can also add elements like this:

```
@folder.elements.create(...)
```

Comment: @folder.elements.create(...) is an excellent and clear way to do this

Comment: I really like @folder.elements.create(...)

This error only appears on unit tests. The fixtures are wrong :(

Thank you, bjg